# Policy to prevent adding users of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the Chrome UI, there's an avatar displayed next to the settings dots which when pressed allows the user to perform actions related to users of Chrome.  They can add a user.  If they go into 'other people' settings they can remove a previously added user.  And the user can chose to sign in if they want to sync things like bookmarks across devices.

There's also a guest option, which allows a guest user to have their own temporary profile; this allows someone to use Chrome without messing up the other persons history, bookmarks or cookies.  This guest account can be turned off by using the [BrowserGuestModeEnabled](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=BrowserGuestModeEnabled) Chrome policy.

How can I prevent the user from adding additional accounts (or removing any that are in place)?  I thought maybe [BrowserSignin](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=BrowserSign) would work, but it doesn't seem to be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  [BrowserAddPersonEnabled](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=BrowserAddPersonEnabled)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this:

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v BrowserAddPersonEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0

in the command prompt (run it as an administrator).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add for Mac users you can disable adding profiles on chrome with the following command in your terminal:

defaults write com.google.Chrome BrowserAddPersonEnabled -bool false

In fact you can search for all the different polices [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/) and then set them true/false in this way through the terminal, of course by replacing "BrowserAddPersonEnabled" with the policy you want to set. Some policies use 1 or 0 integers to set the state of the policy. In that case replace "-bool false" with "-ineger 0". Basically just define the value type and then value itself. Hope this helps people